# How to expand all nodes of a WPF treeview in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, expand

I might be suffering of Monday's dumbness, but I can't find a nice way of expanding all treeview nodes after I've added them in code behind (something like treeView.ExpandAll()).

Any quick help?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In xaml you could do it as follows :

```
 <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
 </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 7):

After playing around with all of the various methods for fully expanding and collapsing a tree view, by far the fastest method is the following. This method seems to work on very large trees.

Ensure your tree is virtualized, if it isn't virtualized then as soon as the tree gets to any kind of size it is going to become painfully slow whatever you do.

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

Assume that you have a view model backing your tree, each node on that view model that corresponds to a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` needs an `IsExpanded` property (it doesn't need to implement property changed). Assume these view models implement an interface like this:

```
interface IExpandableItem : IEnumerable
{
    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

The `TreeViewItem` style needs to be set as follows to bind the `IsExpanded` property in the view model to the view:

```
<Style
    TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter
        Property="IsExpanded"
        Value="{Binding
            IsExpanded,
            Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```

We are going to use this property to set the expansion state, but also, because the tree is virtualized this property is necessary to maintain the correct view state as the individual `TreeViewItem`s get recycled. Without this binding nodes will get collapsed as they go out of view as the user browses the tree.

The only way to get acceptable speed on large trees is to work in code behind in the view layer. The plan is basically as follows:

1. Get hold of the current binding to the `TreeView.ItemsSource`.
2. Clear that binding.
3. Wait for the binding to actually clear.
4. Set the expansion state in the (now unbound) view model.
5. Rebind the `TreeView.ItemsSource` using the binding we cached in step 1.

Because we have virtualization enabled, performing a bind on `TreeView.ItemsSource` turns out to be very fast, even with a large view model. Likewise, when unbound updating the expansion state of the nodes should be very fast. This results in surprisingly fast updates.

Here is some code:

```
void SetExpandedStateInView(bool isExpanded)
{
    var model = this.DataContext as TreeViewModel;
    if (model == null)
    {
        // View model is not bound so do nothing.
        return;
    }

    // Grab hold of the current ItemsSource binding.
    var bindingExpression = this.TreeView.GetBindingExpression(
        ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
    if (bindingExpression == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Clear that binding.
    var itemsSourceBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
    BindingOperations.ClearBinding(
    this.TreeView, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);

    // Wait for the binding to clear and then set the expanded state of the view model.
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.DataBind, 
        new Action(() => SetExpandedStateInModel(model.Items, isExpanded)));

    // Now rebind the ItemsSource.
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.DataBind,
        new Action(
            () => this.TreeView.SetBinding(
                ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding)));
}

void SetExpandedStateInModel(IEnumerable modelItems, bool isExpanded)
{
    if (modelItems == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var modelItem in modelItems)
    {
        var expandable = modelItem as IExpandableItem;
        if (expandable == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        expandable.IsExpanded = isExpanded;
        SetExpandedStateInModel(expandable, isExpanded);
    }
}
```

Comment: Real life  saver!

Answer (score 2):

WPF doesn't have an ExpandAll method. You'll need to loop through and set the property on each node.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834081/wpf-treeview-where-is-the-expandall-method) or [this blog post](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=55).

Answer (score 0):

I have done an ExpandAll that works also if your tree is set for virtualization (recycling items).

This is my code. Perhaps you should consider wrapping your hierarchy into a hierarchical model model view ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using HQ.Util.General;

namespace HQ.Util.Wpf.WpfUtil
{
    public static class TreeViewExtensions
    {
        // ******************************************************************
        public delegate void OnTreeViewVisible(TreeViewItem tvi);
        public delegate void OnItemExpanded(TreeViewItem tvi, object item);
        public delegate void OnAllItemExpanded();

        // ******************************************************************
        private static void SetItemHierarchyVisible(ItemContainerGenerator icg, IList listOfRootToNodeItemPath, OnTreeViewVisible onTreeViewVisible = null)
        {
            Debug.Assert(icg != null);

            if (icg != null)
            {
                if (listOfRootToNodeItemPath.Count == 0) // nothing to do
                    return;

                TreeViewItem tvi = icg.ContainerFromItem(listOfRootToNodeItemPath[0]) as TreeViewItem;
                if (tvi != null) // Due to threading, always better to verify
                {
                    listOfRootToNodeItemPath.RemoveAt(0);

                    if (listOfRootToNodeItemPath.Count == 0)
                    {
                        if (onTreeViewVisible != null)
                            onTreeViewVisible(tvi);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!tvi.IsExpanded)
                            tvi.IsExpanded = true;

                        SetItemHierarchyVisible(tvi.ItemContainerGenerator, listOfRootToNodeItemPath, onTreeViewVisible);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ActionHolder actionHolder = new ActionHolder();
                    EventHandler itemCreated = delegate(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
                        {
                            var icgSender = sender as ItemContainerGenerator;
                            tvi = icgSender.ContainerFromItem(listOfRootToNodeItemPath[0]) as TreeViewItem;
                            if (tvi != null) // Due to threading, it is always better to verify
                            {
                                SetItemHierarchyVisible(icg, listOfRootToNodeItemPath, onTreeViewVisible);

                                actionHolder.Execute();
                            }
                        };

                    actionHolder.Action = new Action(() => icg.StatusChanged -= itemCreated);
                    icg.StatusChanged += itemCreated;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// You cannot rely on this method to be synchronous. If you have any action that depend on the TreeViewItem 
        /// (last item of collectionOfRootToNodePath) to be visible, you should set it in the 'onTreeViewItemVisible' method.
        /// This method should work for Virtualized and non virtualized tree.
        /// The difference with ExpandItem is that this one open up the tree up to the target but will not expand the target itself,
        /// while ExpandItem expand the target itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="treeView">TreeView where  an item has to be set visible</param>
        /// <param name="listOfRootToNodePath">Any collectionic List. The collection should have every objet of the path to the targeted item from the root
        /// to the target. For example for an apple tree: AppleTree (index 0), Branch4, SubBranch3, Leaf2 (index 3)</param>
        /// <param name="onTreeViewVisible">Optionnal</param>
        public static void SetItemHierarchyVisible(this TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<object> listOfRootToNodePath, OnTreeViewVisible onTreeViewVisible = null)
        {
            ItemContainerGenerator icg = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator;
            if (icg == null)
                return; // Is tree loaded and initialized ???

            SetItemHierarchyVisible(icg, new List<object>(listOfRootToNodePath), onTreeViewVisible);
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        private static void ExpandItem(ItemContainerGenerator icg, IList listOfRootToNodePath, OnTreeViewVisible onTreeViewVisible = null)
        {
            Debug.Assert(icg != null);

            if (icg != null)
            {
                if (listOfRootToNodePath.Count == 0) // nothing to do
                    return;

                TreeViewItem tvi = icg.ContainerFromItem(listOfRootToNodePath[0]) as TreeViewItem;
                if (tvi != null) // Due to threading, always better to verify
                {
                    listOfRootToNodePath.RemoveAt(0);

                    if (!tvi.IsExpanded)
                        tvi.IsExpanded = true;

                    if (listOfRootToNodePath.Count == 0)
                    {
                        if (onTreeViewVisible != null)
                            onTreeViewVisible(tvi);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SetItemHierarchyVisible(tvi.ItemContainerGenerator, listOfRootToNodePath, onTreeViewVisible);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ActionHolder actionHolder = new ActionHolder();
                    EventHandler itemCreated = delegate(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
                        {
                            var icgSender = sender as ItemContainerGenerator;
                            tvi = icgSender.ContainerFromItem(listOfRootToNodePath[0]) as TreeViewItem;
                            if (tvi != null) // Due to threading, it is always better to verify
                            {
                                SetItemHierarchyVisible(icg, listOfRootToNodePath, onTreeViewVisible);

                                actionHolder.Execute();
                            }
                        };

                    actionHolder.Action = new Action(() => icg.StatusChanged -= itemCreated);
                    icg.StatusChanged += itemCreated;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// You cannot rely on this method to be synchronous. If you have any action that depend on the TreeViewItem 
        /// (last item of collectionOfRootToNodePath) to be visible, you should set it in the 'onTreeViewItemVisible' method.
        /// This method should work for Virtualized and non virtualized tree.
        /// The difference with SetItemHierarchyVisible is that this one open the target while SetItemHierarchyVisible does not try to expand the target.
        /// (SetItemHierarchyVisible just ensure the target will be visible)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="treeView">TreeView where  an item has to be set visible</param>
        /// <param name="listOfRootToNodePath">The collection should have every objet of the path, from the root to the targeted item.
        /// For example for an apple tree: AppleTree (index 0), Branch4, SubBranch3, Leaf2</param>
        /// <param name="onTreeViewVisible">Optionnal</param>
        public static void ExpandItem(this TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<object> listOfRootToNodePath, OnTreeViewVisible onTreeViewVisible = null)
        {
            ItemContainerGenerator icg = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator;
            if (icg == null)
                return; // Is tree loaded and initialized ???

            ExpandItem(icg, new List<object>(listOfRootToNodePath), onTreeViewVisible);
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        private static void ExpandSubWithContainersGenerated(ItemsControl ic, Action<TreeViewItem, object> actionItemExpanded, ReferenceCounterTracker referenceCounterTracker)
        {
            ItemContainerGenerator icg = ic.ItemContainerGenerator;
            foreach (object item in ic.Items)
            {
                var tvi = icg.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
                actionItemExpanded(tvi, item);
                tvi.IsExpanded = true;
                ExpandSubContainers(tvi, actionItemExpanded, referenceCounterTracker);
            }
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Expand any ItemsControl (TreeView, TreeViewItem, ListBox, ComboBox, ...) and their childs if any (TreeView)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ic"></param>
        /// <param name="actionItemExpanded"></param>
        /// <param name="referenceCounterTracker"></param>
        public static void ExpandSubContainers(ItemsControl ic, Action<TreeViewItem, object> actionItemExpanded, ReferenceCounterTracker referenceCounterTracker)
        {
            ItemContainerGenerator icg = ic.ItemContainerGenerator;
            {
                if (icg.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
                {
                    ExpandSubWithContainersGenerated(ic, actionItemExpanded, referenceCounterTracker);
                }
                else if (icg.Status == GeneratorStatus.NotStarted)
                {
                    ActionHolder actionHolder = new ActionHolder();
                    EventHandler itemCreated = delegate(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
                        {
                            var icgSender = sender as ItemContainerGenerator;
                            if (icgSender.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
                            {
                                ExpandSubWithContainersGenerated(ic, actionItemExpanded, referenceCounterTracker);

                                // Never use the following method in BeginInvoke due to ICG recycling. The same icg could be 
                                // used and will keep more than one subscribers which is far from being intended
                                //  ic.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(actionHolder.Action, DispatcherPriority.Background);

                                // Very important to unsubscribe as soon we've done due to ICG recycling.
                                actionHolder.Execute();

                                referenceCounterTracker.ReleaseRef();
                            }
                        };

                    referenceCounterTracker.AddRef();
                    actionHolder.Action = new Action(() => icg.StatusChanged -= itemCreated);
                    icg.StatusChanged += itemCreated;

                    // Next block is only intended to protect against any race condition (I don't know if it is possible ? How Microsoft implemented it)
                    // I mean the status changed before I subscribe to StatusChanged but after I made the check about its state.
                    if (icg.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
                    {
                        ExpandSubWithContainersGenerated(ic, actionItemExpanded, referenceCounterTracker);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// This method is asynchronous.
        /// Expand all items and subs recursively if any. Does support virtualization (item recycling).
        /// But honestly, make you a favor, make your life easier en create a model view around your hierarchy with
        /// a IsExpanded property for each node level and bind it to each TreeView node level.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="treeView"></param>
        /// <param name="actionItemExpanded"></param>
        /// <param name="actionAllItemExpanded"></param>
        public static void ExpandAll(this TreeView treeView, Action<TreeViewItem, object> actionItemExpanded = null, Action actionAllItemExpanded = null)
        {
            var referenceCounterTracker = new ReferenceCounterTracker(actionAllItemExpanded);
            referenceCounterTracker.AddRef();
            treeView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ExpandSubContainers(treeView, actionItemExpanded, referenceCounterTracker)), DispatcherPriority.Background);
            referenceCounterTracker.ReleaseRef();
        }

        // ******************************************************************
    }
}
```

And

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace HQ.Util.General
{
    public class ReferenceCounterTracker
    {
        private Action _actionOnCountReachZero = null;
        private int _count = 0;

        public ReferenceCounterTracker(Action actionOnCountReachZero)
        {
            _actionOnCountReachZero = actionOnCountReachZero;
        }

        public void AddRef()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        }

        public void ReleaseRef()
        {
            int count = Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
            if (count == 0)
            {
                if (_actionOnCountReachZero != null)
                {
                    _actionOnCountReachZero();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the following method in your project:

```
 private void ExpandAllNodes(TreeViewItem treeItem)
    {
        treeItem.IsExpanded = true;
        foreach (var childItem in treeItem.Items.OfType<TreeViewItem>())
        {
            ExpandAllNodes(childItem);
        }
    }
```

then, you only need to call it like this:

```
treeView.Items.OfType<TreeViewItem>().ToList().ForEach(ExpandAllNodes);
```