# WPF TreeView expand roots only

Tags: wpf, treeview

All root items in the TreeView should be expanded by default. Root items have a separate ViewModel from child items.

Treeview XAML:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:RootModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Roots}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Child1Model}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Child2Model}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The hierarchy is like so:

[image: treeview item hierarchy]

All items with the root viewmodel should be expanded while all child items are collapsed. How do I achieve this behavior? I am still very new to WPF so I didnt really know what to do, but I tried following things after some 'research':

Define a `IsExpanded` property in the view model: Obviously it wont be used.

```
private bool _isExpanded = true;
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get => _isExpanded;
    set
    {
        _isExpanded = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsExpanded)); //base.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Apply a style to the `HierachicalDataTemplate`: it doesnot support styling of the TreeViewItem itself, only the container.

```
<Style x:Key="RootItem" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:RootModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Roots}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RootItem}">
```

I found an answer how to set expand all `TreeViewItems` but I have no way of modifying it to only affect one itemtype/viewmodel. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6952701/6401643

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to bind the `TreeViewItem` property `IsExpanded` to my viewmodel via the above mentioned answer.
In my viewmodel I defined the property `IsExpanded`:

```
private bool _isExpanded = true;
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get => _isExpanded;
    set
    {
        _isExpanded = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsExpanded)); //base.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And then two-way bound it to the TreeViewItem property:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Still; wired that it didnt work with the style I tried, since this effectively is the same.